# Is the blassoAveraged model in caret is really a ridge model?

Tags: r-caret, bayesian, lasso-regression

This might be simple, but why is the blassoAveraged model labeled as "Bayesian Ridge Regression (Model Averaged)"? Shouldn't it be Bayesian Lasso? Or the average of several L1 normalization models has an end-effect similar to L2?

Thanks,

Gustavo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more a question for the caret developers than it is for the SO community. Post it as [an issue to the GitHub repository](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues). It does have some theory, so [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) could also be appropriate.